# Perforce: Set up Workspace by copying existing workspace?

Tags: perforce, workspace

My project is somewhere in the order of 100 GB per stream, with an additional 60 GB added to each workspace for local local cache files.

Rather than downloading and rebuilding from the depot every time I need a workspace for a new stream, is there a way to copy a workspace I already have downloaded and set up, then have Perforce recognize it as part of a different stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where your first workspace is `clientA` rooted at `/home/clientA` and your new workspace is going to be `clientB`, do:

```
cp -r /home/clientA/ /home/clientB/
p4 set P4CLIENT=clientB                   # or use P4CONFIG files
p4 client -t clientA
p4 sync -k @clientA
p4 clean
```

Now you have `clientB` set up as a copy of `clientA` -- the `sync -k` command tells the server "sync everything that `clientA` has but don't send me the actual files, just pretend that I synced them."  The `p4 clean` command should be a no-op, but if you somehow messed up the copy or you had open files in `clientA` or something, this will fix it by forcing a re-sync of the files that are wrong.

Now that you've done that you can do:

```
p4 switch STREAMNAME
```

which will switch you to a different stream, syncing only the files that are different.  Many people just have a single workspace and use `p4 switch` to hop between streams; it automatically stashes your work in progress and everything, and you conserve local disk space by not having multiple copies of everything.  (A good case for having multiple workspaces would be if you have the space to spare and you don't want to rebuild those 60GB of cache files each time your workspace contents change...)

Comment: Does this handle the case where stream A and stream B are not identical?

Comment: That's what the `p4 switch STREAMNAME` is for.  Start by having the two clients reference the same stream, then use `p4 switch` to switch streams on one of them.  `p4 switch` is smart and will do the right thing.